# Fill missing values with zeros for list of unevenly spaced points

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plot, interpolation

I have a set of points saved as a dataframe **dp**:

```
xlist   ylist
0   0.017108    0.902494
1   0.019659    0.741981
2   0.030310    0.920884
3   0.032064    0.255826
4   0.046168    0.562761
5   0.060758    0.583044
6   0.118274    1.000000
7   0.125385    1.000000
8   0.140418    1.000000
9   0.153699    1.000000
10  0.186998    0.293743
11  0.215375    0.112288
12  0.217875    0.260883
13  0.250591    0.325953
14  0.262788    0.084916
15  0.287382    0.104910
16  0.325902    0.088418
17  0.377885    0.312025
18  0.473086    0.068632
19  0.485449    0.059624
20  0.557334    0.734376
21  0.572133    0.709392
22  0.610553    0.840687
23  0.626902    0.737930
24  0.630276    0.084787
25  0.637779    0.091535
26  0.717553    0.074411
27  0.742187    0.092770
28  0.757873    0.532881
29  0.780933    0.528202
30  0.836708    0.422615
31  0.920814    0.359896
32  0.938639    0.355241
33  0.954564    0.280989
34  0.978567    0.649749
35  0.995067    0.769272
```

They look like this using pyplot.vlines:

```
[plt.vlines(x,0,y) for x,y in zip(dp.xlist, dp.ylist)]
plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like to replace **xlist** with:

```
x = linspace(0,1,num=100) ###(or num=200... not important)
```

and create a new **y**, using values from ylist where **x** is close to xlist, and zeros elsewhere.
What I've tried so far is for every pair of **xlist, ylist** values I check if there is a point in my linear space close enough to the point in xlist and then assign it the corresponding value of ylist, else, I put a zero.

```
for i in dp.index:

    fill = [] 

    for xa in x:
        if abs(dp.xlist[i]-xa)<0.001:
            tmp = dp.ylist[i]
        else:
            tmp = 0
        fill.append(tmp)
```

But I think I'm overwriting the list "fill", that's why it will not work, but I don't know how to fix this.

Is there a quick and simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried any of them :  [fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), [replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for loops. You can use pandas methods:

```
dp['x_lin'] = x[np.abs(np.subtract.outer(x,dp.xlist.values)).argmin(0)]
dp['y_lin'] = 0
dp.y_lin[np.abs(dp.x_lin-dp.xlist)<0.001] = dp.ylist
```

you could also replace first line with equivalent:

```
dp['x_lin'] = x[np.abs(x[None,:]-dp.xlist[:,None]).argmin(1)]
```

output:

```
       xlist     ylist     x_lin     y_lin
0   0.017108  0.902494  0.020202  0.000000
1   0.019659  0.741981  0.020202  0.741981
2   0.030310  0.920884  0.030303  0.920884
3   0.032064  0.255826  0.030303  0.000000
4   0.046168  0.562761  0.050505  0.000000
5   0.060758  0.583044  0.060606  0.583044
6   0.118274  1.000000  0.121212  0.000000
7   0.125385  1.000000  0.121212  0.000000
8   0.140418  1.000000  0.141414  1.000000
9   0.153699  1.000000  0.151515  0.000000
10  0.186998  0.293743  0.191919  0.000000
11  0.215375  0.112288  0.212121  0.000000
12  0.217875  0.260883  0.222222  0.000000
13  0.250591  0.325953  0.252525  0.000000
14  0.262788  0.084916  0.262626  0.084916
15  0.287382  0.104910  0.282828  0.000000
16  0.325902  0.088418  0.323232  0.000000
17  0.377885  0.312025  0.373737  0.000000
18  0.473086  0.068632  0.474747  0.000000
19  0.485449  0.059624  0.484848  0.059624
20  0.557334  0.734376  0.555556  0.000000
21  0.572133  0.709392  0.575758  0.000000
22  0.610553  0.840687  0.606061  0.000000
23  0.626902  0.737930  0.626263  0.737930
24  0.630276  0.084787  0.626263  0.000000
25  0.637779  0.091535  0.636364  0.000000
26  0.717553  0.074411  0.717172  0.074411
27  0.742187  0.092770  0.737374  0.000000
28  0.757873  0.532881  0.757576  0.532881
29  0.780933  0.528202  0.777778  0.000000
30  0.836708  0.422615  0.838384  0.000000
31  0.920814  0.359896  0.919192  0.000000
32  0.938639  0.355241  0.939394  0.355241
33  0.954564  0.280989  0.959596  0.000000
34  0.978567  0.649749  0.979798  0.000000
35  0.995067  0.769272  1.000000  0.000000
```

output plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks good.

Yes, you are overwriting fill for every `i`. But you are also adding the tmp for every xa. I don't quite know what your x is. But try:

```
fill = [] 
for i in dp.index:
    tmp = 0
    for xa in x:
        if abs(dp.xlist[i]-xa)<0.001:
            tmp = dp.ylist[i]
    fill.append(tmp)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is the best method to achieve what I need, it's not working.